# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError deploy lambda django with zappa

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried to deploy my django project through zappa to create lambda and I got this error, can anyone help me with this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\parsers.py", line 504, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
    root = parser.close()
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0 


raise ResponseParserError(
botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, I had to create an aws-cli user profile again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).